# C++ : how base class member variables are initialized properly without defining parameterized constructor?

Tags: c++11

Scenario 1: No compilation issue.When base class is initialized in derived class using initialization list

```
class Base
{
    public:
        int x;
};
class D:public Base
{
    public:
        int y;
        D(int y1):Base{y1+1},y{y1}{}
};

int main()
{
    D d(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Scenario 2: Not compiling and asking for parameterized constructor . Note virtual destructor in base class
$g++ -o main *.cpp
main.cpp: In constructor ‘D::D(int)’:
main.cpp:16:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’
         D(int y1):Base{y1+1},y{y1}{}
                                  ^
main.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: Base::Base()
 class Base
       ^~~~
main.cpp:5:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
main.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: constexpr Base::Base(const Base&)
main.cpp:5:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const Base&’

```
class Base
{
    public:
    int x;
    virtual ~Base(){}    
};
class D:public Base
{
    public:
        int y;
        D(int y1):Base{y1+1},y{y1}{}
};

int main()
{
    D d(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Base{y1+1}` is an [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). It only works on aggregates. In your second snippet, since `Base` contains a virtual function, it is no longer an aggregate, and so you can't initialize it like that.